# Flask sqlalchemy insert json values into table without reading each colunm

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

**Model**

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, Sequence("user_id_sq"), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(20))
    fullname = Column(String(50))
    password = Column(String(20))

    def __init__(self, id, name, fullname, password):
        """"""
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.fullname = fullname
        self.password = password

    def __repr__(self):
       return "<User(name='%s', fullname='%s', password='%s')>" % (
                             self.name, self.fullname, self.password)
```

**DATA**

```
data = {"id":1,"name":"Eswar","fullname":"S","password":"123456aA"}

user_data = User(data["id"],
                 data["name"],
                 data["fullname"],
                 data["password"])
```

Instead of reading each value by keys of user_data is there any way we can insert data into table with respective values into columns.

Comment: If the keys in the `data` dictionary match the argument names in the `__init__` method this should work `User(**data)`.

Comment: I think also you should be able to do `User.__table__.insert().execute(data)`

Comment: User.__table__.insert().execute(data) using this Im getting......"sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: This None is not directly bound to a Connection or Engine.Use the .execute() method of a Connection or Engine to execute this construct."

Comment: Thank you IanAuld. Whats the simplest way to insert if keys and column name are different? Instead of reading each key value.

Comment: If the keys don't match the column names, you either write them all out as you did or you define a mapping and do something like `User(**{mapping.get(key, key): value for key, value in data.items()})` where `mapping` contains fields that aren't exact matches.